# Equivalent of parent parentDocument from flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, apache-royale

I must turn a Flex code into an Apache Royale one but in my research, there is on attribute for which i dont find the equivalent.

In Flex, to call an actionScipt function from a parent mxml, I have:

`<mx:Button label="Login" click="parentDocument.myfunction()"/>`

I found parentComponent during my research, but i have ***Access of possibly undefined property parentComponent*** error.

I also tried just 'parent' and the error became ***Call to a possibly undefined method verif_sharedobject through a reference with static type IParent.***

I did some research about IParent, Container and Group (From jewel) but for the moment I have no success

Answer (score 0):

please check `ParentDocumentBead` bead from `Core` library.

From asdoc :

```
     *  The ParentDocumentBead class looks up the parent
     *  chain to find a parent that was written in MXML.
     *  Because it is usually rare for an application
     *  to need to know this information, an optional bead
     *  is used to compute it, instead of baking in the
     *  overhead of a recursive infrastucture to store
     *  this information.  It is intended to be used
     *  as a bead in the top-level tag of an MXML document.
```

HTH